# Expressing the Gradient in terms of an Arbitrary Scalar Product

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

As part of determining the expression for the gradient in terms of an arbitrary inner product, I arrived at the following problem:
Given:

- $y = (y^1, \dots, y^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a selected point
- $h = (h^1, \dots, h^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is an arbitrary point.
- $f$ is a real-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$
- $[g_{ij}]$ is a positive definite, symmetric  $n \times n$ matrix

I'm trying to show that

$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \partial_{j}f(x_0)h^j = \sum\limits_{j,k=1}^n g_{jk}y^j h^k  
$$

implies

$$
\partial_{j} f(x_0) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n g_{jk}y^k
$$

The only way I can reasonably see how to arrive at the conclusion is to reason as follows: Since the antecedent holds for arbitrary points in $\mathbb{R}^n$
it must hold for the particular $n$ points associated with the standard basis vectors $e_1, \dots, e_n$ So, for example, if we take the first point
$h = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$ it follows that $\partial_{1}f(x_0) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n g_{1k}y^k$ and so on and hence for the $j^{th}$ point we have the conclusion above.

So, my questions:

- Is this line of reasoning correct?
- Is there a better or more direct way to demonstrate the conclusion?

EDIT

I'm updating this post to provide additional contextual information.

Given that $[g_{ij}]$ is a positive-definite and symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, it can be shown that the function

$$
(. | . )^g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$

given by

$$
(x | y)^g = \sum\limits_{j,k=1}^n g_{jk}y^j x^k
$$

is a scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Now, let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is differentiable at $x_0$. By the Riesz represenation theorem 
(for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces) since $df(x_0)$ is a continuous
linear form there exists a unique vector $y$ such that $df(x_0)h  = (y | h)^g \; \forall h\in \mathbb{R^n}$

This unique vector $y$ is defined to be the **gradient of $f$ at $x_0$ with respect to the scalar product $(x | y)^g$ and is denoted by $y = \nabla^g f(x_0)$** 
I am working through the details of the proof that

$$
\nabla^g f(x_0) = (g^{1k}\partial_{k}f(x_0), \dots, g^{nk}\partial_{k}f(x_0)) 
$$

where the repeated upper/lower indices indication summation from $1 \dots n$ and $g^{ij}$ represents the $i-j$ entry of the inverse of the matrix $[g_{ij}]$

Comment: Yes, your line of reasoning is correct.

Comment: What you're saying seems correct, but I'm a bit puzzled because of your motivation. Don't you want to show that there exists a unique $y$ such that $df(x_0) h = g(y,h)$ for all $h$, so how can $y$ be selected? To see the existence and uniqueness of $y$ simply note that it must be $g$-orthogonal to the $(n-1)$-dimensional kernel of $df(x_0)$ (if the kernel is $n$-dimensional then $y$ must be zero by positive-definiteness of $g$), so choose such a vector and scale it appropriately.

Comment: @Theo I have updated the post to provide additional information so that the context of the question will hopefully be more clear.

Comment: I'm still puzzled. You can just take your candidate for $\nabla^g f(x_0)$ and *check* that $df(x_0)h = g(\nabla^g f(x_0),h)$ for all $h$ which is what you want and rather tautologically true. Or do you want to see how to *find* this candidate? Be that as it may, I'd say you've got everything you need already worked out :)

Comment: Hi 3Sphere: Did you get where I'm heading?

Comment: @Theo Yes, thanks for following up, and the help. I completed working out the construction (meaning, deriving the result and not just verifying it). Basically, all I needed to do was to finish up with some basic matrix algebra.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point I was trying to make. Okay, very good, then. See you around!

Answer (score 1):

If you implant
$${\rm grad}f\cdot h^{\top}=yG\cdot h^{\top}$$ for all $h$, 
then
$$({\rm grad}f-yG)\cdot h^{\top}=0$$

so ${\rm grad }f=yG$ is exactly what you are claiming.

The qualities of $Q$ makes no difference.